# page is not displaying, php project on iis

Tags: iis

I have done all IIS and PHP manager configuration 
and created one website called website1 and I set the ip address and name website1.net in host file, when I click browse in IIS the result is page cant be displayed. any solutions ?

Comment: What exactly is the error?

Comment: error was page can't be displayed ,  i solved by executing batch file ... thanks @JTC

Comment: If you found the answer, post it below and accept it.